Не работает обработка ссылки. Telegram Bot
При создании бота решил сделать хорошо и интересно оформленную информацию о нём. Появилась идея внедрить в каждый из пунктов списка "Содержание" ссылку, перейдя по которой пользователя отправит в того же бота, но вместо /start должна обрабатываться соответствующая функция, в которой будет описан пункт списка. Но, как бы я не старался, всё равно запускается /start вместо нужной функции. Ссылка создаётся правильно, но скорее всего неправильно обрабатывается, не знаю как исправить.
Код:
# Словарь для хранения описаний разделов
sections = {
    "О боте": "Описание бота",
    "Функции": "Описание функций бота",
    "Функции/connect": "Описание функции /connect",
    "Функции/create": "Описание функции /create",
    "Обозначения": "Описание обозначений",
    "Внутрянка": "Описание внутреннего устройства",
    "Будущее": "Описание планов на будущее",
}


#* Обработчик команды "/help"
@dp.message(Command("help"))
async def help(message: types.Message):
    # Формируем текст сообщения с ссылками на команды
    help_text = "<b>Содержание:</b>\n"
    help_text += "├ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=about'>О боте</a>\n"
    help_text += "├ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=features'>Функции</a>\n"
    help_text += "  ├ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=helpconnect'>/connect</a>\n"
    help_text += "  └ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=helpcreate'>/create</a>\n"
    help_text += "├ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=notations'>Обозначения</a>\n"
    help_text += "├ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=inner'>Внутрянка</a>\n"
    help_text += "└ <a href='t.me/AHelpTbot?start=future'>Будущее</a>\n"

    await message.reply(
        text=help_text,
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /about
@dp.message(Command("about"))
async def about(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["О боте"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /features
@dp.message(Command("features"))
async def features(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Функции"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /helpconnect
@dp.message(Command("helpconnect"))
async def connect(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Функции/connect"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /helpcreate
@dp.message(Command("helpcreate"))
async def create(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Функции/create"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /notations
@dp.message(Command("notations"))
async def notations(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Обозначения"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /inner
@dp.message(Command("inner"))
async def inner(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Внутрянка"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


# Функция для команды /future
@dp.message(Command("future"))
async def future(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=sections["Будущее"],
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


Вообще, довольно сомнительное решение. При переходе по такой ссылке, всегда будет появляться кнопка старт. Можно запихнуть функции обработки аргумента в хендлер, который обрабатывает команду start

как по мне, это выглядит лучше чем кнопки. я пытался сделать это как содержание в какой-нибудь документации, например, к самой библиотеке Aiogram. утром нашел решение, есть выйдет - отвечу на свой же вопрос и буду рад. если не выйдет - расстроюсь и буду пользоваться костылями, например telegram.ph

Каждый раз при переходе по ссылке - это как новый запуск бота и постоянное наличие сообщения с текстом /start выглядит лучше, чем сообщение с названием выбранного пункта меню? Кроме того, ссылки выглядят лучше, чем кнопки? Вот это меня удивило. Ну, хозяин - барин)

этим способом можно лучше обозначить "путь" к пункту

Это как это "обозначить путь"? Большая кнопка с одной стороны, которая, в целом, выглядит не плохо, и список ссылок с другой. Не понимаю

Параметр start в вашей ссылке - это параметр, который вы можете получить в хендлере своей команды при помощи message.get_args().
Через этот параметр вы не сможете отправить команду от имени пользователя.
Для ваших целей лучше подходят ReplyKeyboardMarkup

я нашел решение!
к сожалению, у меня не вышло создание ссылки с помощью create_start_link(), но обработку ссылки я всё же сделал.
#* Обработчик команды "/help"
@dp.message(Command("help"))
async def help(message: types.Message):
    # Формируем текст сообщения с ссылками на команды
    help_text = "<b>Содержание:</b>\n"
    help_text += f"├ <a href='{link}about'>О боте</a>\n"
    help_text += f"├ <a href='{link}features'>Функции</a>\n"
    help_text += f"  ├ <a href='{link}helpconnect'>/connect</a>\n"
    help_text += f"  └ <a href='{link}helpcreate'>/create</a>\n"
    help_text += f"├ <a href='{link}notations'>Обозначения</a>\n"
    help_text += f"├ <a href='{link}inner'>Внутрянка</a>\n"
    help_text += f"└ <a href='{link}future'>Будущее</a>\n"

    await message.reply(
        text=help_text,
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )

#* Обработчик команды "/start"
@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def handler(message: Message, command: CommandObject):
    args = command.args
    if args == "about":
        await message.reply(
            text=sections["О боте"],
            parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
        )
     # и так далее...

для использования заполняем:
sections = {
    "О боте": "Описание бота",
    "Функции": "Описание функций бота",
    "Функции/connect": "Описание функции /connect",
    "Функции/create": "Описание функции /create",
    "Обозначения": "Описание обозначений",
    "Внутрянка": "Описание внутреннего устройства",
    "Будущее": "Описание планов на будущее",
}

